# Owl Carousel 2 switches to default position after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a real noob at js so I hope I'll find working solution to solve my problem. I'm working on Drupal 7 project based on Porto template v.2.1 using Dupal Commerce module. I've implemented Owl Carousel 2 v. 2.1.0 with jQuery 1.12.3. 
At the product display page I have few attribute widgets which are carousels. All my carousels items are clickable (product attributes which loads big picture of a model with related attributes by Ajax calls). One widget has more than 30 items (models which are taxonomy terms), now it has just 14 items. So I call for that widget (div) carousel plugin with following code:

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
      attach: function (context) {
        $('.attribute-widgets > div > div ').addClass("owl-carousel");
        $('.attribute-widgets > div > div ').addClass("owl-theme");
        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
            owl.owlCarousel({
                dots: false,
                margin: 10,
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive:{
                    640:{
                        items:3,
                        nav: true,
                        navText: "",
                    },
                    768:{
                        items:4,
                        nav: true,
                        navText: "",
                    },
                    1024:{
                        items:7,
                        nav: true,
                        navText: "",
                    },
                    1280:{
                        items:9,
                        nav: true,
                        navText: "",
                    },
                    1366:{
                        items:10,
                        nav: true,
                        navText: "",
                    },
                    1600:{
                        items:13,
                        nav: true,
                        navText: "",
                    },
                } 
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the current version of that website I have done by this moment: [Dev site](http://goo.gl/Rg9kIx)

So the problem is when you move to the last item for example which is not visible when page loads first time and click on that item, carousel switches to it default position and clicked item become not visible, but I want carousel to stay after click in the same position before clicking.

All those color squares below are carousels too which are respresents product attributes such as door color, glass color etc, so those carousels should keep their current positions after their items being clicked.

Is there a possibility to do that by modificating my js code? All matching examples are really appreciated!

Also what I want to make work is when you click on middle+1 item carousel should moves forward for one item, when you click on middle+2 item carousel should moves forward for two items, the same for +3 and +4. And carousel should have possibility to move backwards after clicking middle-1 items, middle-2 item and etc.

Really hope to get real examples of how can I make all this work, cause my knowledge don't allow me to make is by myself.

Thanks in advance, 
Ilya

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason for the owl carousel to reset after an ajax call. Unless.. maybe your ajax is reloading the owl carousel instead of leaving it alone. Unfortunately, the code you provided doesn't tell anything; it's just some basic owl carousel settings. I rather see your ajax code.

Comment: Yes, seems that ajax is reloading the owl carousel instead of leaving it alone. Well actually I develope this website using drupal 7 and drupal modules only without any custom coding exept js plugin which calls owl carousel. Commerce Fancy Attribute module is responsible for loading big picture and related attributes widgets. Where can I find that ajax code to provide it to you?